# How to use response assertion if pagination is applied and you dont know amongst the 3 pages, where the value will appear?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, assertion

Q1 Pagination is applied and I need to validate the response through text response , that value is present or not. SO there are 3 pages due to pagination, so value will appear in one of the three pages. So how and where should i add the response assertion?

Q2 Also if I select(pattern matching rules)as "matches" in response assertion, Then even same values appeared in response, but still assertion is getting failed.
For example: Under (pattern to test) I have added text to validate
"document":{"id":8},

Same value appeared in response after execution
"document":{"id":8},

But still assertion failed. why so?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

As per [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps) article:

> The Pattern can be either be:
>
> - a “string” for “Equals” or “Substring” clauses
> - a “Perl5-style” Regular Expression for “Contains” or “Matches” clauses

So given you chose "Matches" rule you need to use a [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/), not a string as your input is considered as the [Regular Expression](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

Just switch to "Substring" pattern matching rule and your assertion should start working as expected. If you want to proceed with the regular expression you need to amend your criteria correspondingly:

```
(?s)^.*"document":{"id":8},.*$
```